# converting win app to win service

Tags: c#, windows-services, sms

I'm using this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx to make an application that will send SMS via mobile phone. When I make a GUI win app everything works fine, but when I try to convert that to windows service app (no GUI) to work in the background it tells me no phone connected.

Here are both, very simple, examples:

GUI app

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using GsmComm.GsmCommunication;
using GsmComm.PduConverter;

namespace SMS.Forms
{
    public partial class SendSMS : Form
    {
        SmsSubmitPdu pdu;
        private int port;
        private int baudrate;
        private int timeout;

        public SendSMS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //phone connection
            port = 3;
            baudrate = 115200;
            timeout = 300;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GsmCommMain comm = new GsmCommMain(port, baudrate, timeout);

            try
            {
                comm.Open();

                //send sms
                pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu("Test msg", "0xxxxxxxxx", "");
                comm.SendMessage(pdu);

                comm.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Connection error: " + ex.Message, "Connection setup", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show(this, "Successfully connected to the phone.", "Connection setup", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

WIN service

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using GsmComm.GsmCommunication;
using GsmComm.PduConverter;

namespace SMS
{
    public partial class SendSMS : ServiceBase
    {

        SmsSubmitPdu pdu;

        //logs
        private string sSource;
        private string sLog;
        private string sEvent;

        private int port;
        private int baudrate;
        private int timeout;

        public SendSMS()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //event logs
            sSource = "SendSMS";
            sLog = "SMS";
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(sSource))
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(sSource, sLog);


            //phone connection
            port = 3;
            baudrate = 115200;
            timeout = 300;
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            //logs
            sEvent = "SMS service started";
            EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent);

            GsmCommMain comm = new GsmCommMain(port, baudrate, timeout);

            try
            {
                comm.Open();
                while (!comm.IsConnected())
                {
                    sEvent = "Phone not connected";
                    EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent);
                    comm.Close();
                    return;
                }

                //send sms
                pdu = new SmsSubmitPdu("Test msg", "0xxxxxxxxx", "");
                comm.SendMessage(pdu);

                comm.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                sEvent = "Not done " + ex.Message;
                EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent);
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                comm.Close();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            //logs
            sEvent = "SMS service stopped";
            EventLog.WriteEntry(sSource, sEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the service it writes "Phone not connected" to event log. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Or at least how to pinpoint the error...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing the Phone connection code in the onStart event, you need to create instance of timer class, and check whether the phone is connected on specific intervals. You can start the timer in the onstart event.

Comment: Hmmm, still not working :( I moved the connection to another method, and called it using timer in the onStart... Same thing happens. I've made a method that writes a txt file (just to see if the service works correctly) and called it from the onStart - it works OK. But phone connection doesn't. Is there anything else I could do? Is there a limit what windows service can do (port connections etc)?

Comment: I don't think, Windows Service have a limitation like that, but not sure. Why I told you to put a timer because onStart event starts and finishes when ever you start the service it self.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get any other ideas :(